# Alternative of "can not set both range and type on function declaration" in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am making a verilog code for calculation of `variance`, in my verilog code I am calling a definition file, the definition file is as follows

```
`define MAXIMUM_FUNC_WIDTH  64

function integer clog2(input reg [`MAXIMUM_FUNC_WIDTH-1:0] value); 
    begin 
        value = value-1;
        for (clog2=0; value>0; clog2=clog2+1)
            value = value>>1;
    end 
endfunction

function reg [`MAXIMUM_FUNC_WIDTH-1:0] pow(input integer base, input integer index); 
   begin
       for (pow=1; index>=0; pow=pow*base)
           index = index - 1;
   end
endfunction
```

but in the line  `function reg [MAXIMUM_FUNC_WIDTH-1:0] pow(input integer base, input integer index);` it is showing error like `can not set both range and type on function declaration`. In think this is related to `system verilog`. But how can I use the same line for verilog only.

Comment: Try removing `reg` from the `pow` definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Verilog standard only allowed a simple type name, or a range (assumed to be `reg`, but not both. SystemVerilog allows both as a packed array.